# Validation of viewstate MAC failed in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validation Key and validation algorithm. Auto Generate cannot be used in a cluster.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: `System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.`

Stack Trace:

> [ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate.   Client IP: ::1  Port: 49760
>     Path: /destination.aspx     User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3;
>   WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143
>   Safari/537.36     ViewState:
>   ZDL/pAdYwlwxR8MjOlSwmfHswlju0QqWbFMzwqlou/bDqNjXlwYPnwAafMjAAnvPKVDZ6pGzaQd9ROUxtdS3qg0FIf5H6MxrEcFerM99PRw=]
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If
>   this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that
>    configuration specifies the same validationKey and
>   validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: Check out this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915218

Answer (score 3):

Starting with ASP.NET 4.5.2, the runtime enforces EnableViewStateMac=true.
If an application sets <%@ Page EnableViewStateMac="false" %> as a directive or  as a config setting, the runtime ignores it and pretends that the developer had written "true" instead.
Main reason why they do so - it's not safely.

Answer (score -3):

`Wrote this code in webconfg.`

**Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a web farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.**

```
<pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false"></pages>
```

or

```
<machineKey validation="SHA1" validationKey="A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1B2C3D4E5" decryption="Auto" decryptionKey="A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1"/>
```

[Reference details](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915218)

Comment: Please improve this answer by providing a concise explanation. I think you need to emphasize that the config changes should be applied to all instances.

Comment: This answer is bad. In fact, the linked KB article explicitly states that you should *never* do what this answer is telling you to do.